# How to handle one to many relation ship Knockout-Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, knockout.js

So I have I have a simple structure where one purchase have a collection of expenses, and each expense have an account(plastic, cash, plastic#2...).

So the json my api gets is similar to this:

```
[
{"$id":"1","Id":1,"Name":"apple","Value":100.0,"AccountId":1,"Account":
    {"$id":"2","Id":1,"Name":"Cash"}},
{"$id":"3","Id":2,"Name":"pear","Value":50.0,"AccountId":1,"Account":
    {"$ref":"2"}},
{"$id":"4","Id":3,"Name":"raspberry","Value":10.0,"AccountId":1,"Account":
    {"$ref":"2"}}
]
```

I see my json is not writing my cash account each time it needs it, it is refering it with

```
 {"$ref":"2"}
```

where

```
{"$id":"2","Id":1,"Name":"Cash"}
```

so when I render my table with this html:

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: gastos">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.value"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.account.Name"></td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I get this, because the account for pear, and raspberry are nulls:

[image]

So how do you handle $ref in knockout?

I am mapping to 'gastos' this way:

```
$.getJSON('@ViewBag.GastosUrl', function (data) {
            data.forEach(function(o) {
                gastos.push(new gastoVM(o.Id, o.Name, o.Value, o.Account));
            });
        });

var gastoVM = function(Id, Name, Value, Account) {
        var self = this;

        self.id = Id;
        self.name = Name;
        self.value = Value;
        self.account = Account;
    };
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `entity-framework` but with the data as provided, a couple options available ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjTZX/)):

- Build up the account information alongside the `gastos`. And only provide the `$id` or  `$ref` for later referencing.

  ```
  var vm = {
    gastos: [],

    accounts: {},
    accountLookup: function(accountId){
       return this.accounts[accountId];
    }
  }

  //... inside AJAX call
  var accountId = o.Account["$id"]
  if(accountId)
  {
    vm.accounts[accountId] = o.Account;
  }
  ```
- Use a [ko utility method](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) to lookup the account from within your array.

  ```
  accountLookupByUtil: function(accountId) {

      var gasto =  ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.gastos, function(item) {
        if(item.account['$id'] == accountId)
        {
          return item
        }             
      });

     return gasto.account;
  }
  ```

From the html:

```
<td data-bind="text: $root.accountLookup($data.accountId).Name"></td>
<td data-bind="text: $root.accountLookupByUtil($data.accountId).Name"></td>
```

**Note:** Both methods are available in the fiddle, thus some properties are provided that would not be necessary depending upon the method used.

Comment: How do handle this if you want to make accounts Observable? EDIT, second option would work, nevermind